# Navigate from current location to another location via google maps directions

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2

Is there a way or does google map developers have a framework for direction from your location to the geolocation you are trying to go in android stuio google map using kotlin. I looking for some solution but seems its hard for me to find even reading in google map developers there is none.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an explicit intent to start Google Maps app with the coordinates of your destination as intent parameters.

```kotlin
// Create a Uri from an intent string. Use the result to create an Intent.
val googleMapsIntentUri = Uri.parse(
    "google.navigation:q=$destination_latitude,$destination_longitude"
)

// Create an Intent from googleMapsIntentUri. Set the action to ACTION_VIEW
val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, googleMapsIntentUri)
// Make the Intent explicit by setting the Google Maps package
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")

// Attempt to start an activity that can handle the Intent
startActivity(mapIntent)
```

Comment: I would suggest using [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action) as an URI. This is recommended by Google since they launched Maps URLs API a couple of years ago.

Comment: then how can you use that on the android studio? @xomena

Comment: Instead of string `"google.navigation:q=$destination_latitude,$destination_longitude"` use the Maps URL string `"https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&your_parameters"`.